# Reload directive on data change Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that renders a table in Angular. The table has also sorting by column header. When the page loads everything works fine, but when I load more rows through a service on the table the sorting breaks. The directive initializes a sorting factory with table rows the first time, but after i don't see it updating or being called.

```
var sorter = new DashboardContactSorterFactory($scope.dashboardContactData),
```

I update the contacts for the table on my controller when i select a dropdown value.

Any help on how this sorter can be updated? i tried to do a $watch on the data but it did not work.

Comment: You need to show us some more code.

Comment: Nevermind, I just solver id, the error I was getting on `$watch` was undefined variable, so I moved the declaration at the top as `var sorter;` and then just use it in the code inside `$watch`